# Regex for extracting certain part of a String

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Hey Im trying to extract certain information from a string. The String looks like

> Name: music mix.mp3          Size: 2356KB

I would like to extract the file name only with the extension.
I dont have much knowledge in regex, so I was hoping to get some help here. 
Thanks!

Comment: not to much knowledge in accpet rate as well :)

Comment: In your example, is the filename "music mix.mp3"?

Comment: Yes it is. It's a listbox item btw

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Please check this example:

```
const string str = "Name: music mix.mp3 Size: 2356KB";
var match = Regex.Match(str, "Name: (.*) Size:");
Console.WriteLine("Match: " + match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: +1. might be worth adding a `^` to the start to anchor it; it'll make the regex more efficient.

Answer (score 6):

Solution using regex lookaround feature.

```
String sourcestring = "Name: music mix.mp3 Size: 2356KB";
Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<=^Name: ).+(?= Size:)");
Match m = re.Match(sourcestring);
Console.WriteLine("Match: " + m.Groups[0].Value);
```

[Example code here](http://www.myregextester.com/?r=e8e50ba2)

Answer (score 4):

This is regex

```
Name:\s*(?<FileName>[\w\s]+.\w{3})
```

this regex return the music mix.mp3 in group  if the name of file is with white space

```
       string strRegex = @"Name:\s*(?<FileName>[\w\s]+.\w{3})";

        Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex);
        string strTargetString = @"Name: music mix.mp3 Size: 2356KB";

        Match myMatch = myRegex.Match(strTargetString);

        string fileName = myMatch.Groups["FileName"].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(fileName);
```