# How to get a value attribute from a hidden field using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to parse an html fragment to retrieve some data I need. I tried to find here at SO but couldn't find a solution were you filter by something and get other thing.

I don't need a solution to get all html tags or clear an entirely page. I just want to improve my already functional `Regex`.

The page is 200 lines long and I really want do retrieve on hidden field (**lines were break just to make more readable**):

```
<!-- ...long list of html tags and hidden fields... -->

<input type="hidden" 
   name="javax.faces.ViewState" 
   id="javax.faces.ViewState" 
   value="valueIwant" 
   autocomplete="off" />

<!-- ...more html... -->
```

I need to retrieve the `value` attribute from this element called `javax.faces.ViewState` either by its `name` or `id`.

I end up with this code:

```
string value = Regex.Match(html, "<input[^>]*name=\"(javax.faces.ViewState)\"[^>]*>");
```

This successfully find the exactly tag but retrieve it entirely. What I really want is **improve** this `Regex` to return only the content of `value` attribute.

I don't want to solve this by making `Substring` calls since I don't know exactly the size of this content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex help with extracting certain part of a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650909/regex-help-with-extracting-certain-part-of-a-string)

Comment: @JKarthik Actually the answer there and here end up very different. I think the html part make it worst.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(html, "<input[^>]*name=\"javax.faces.ViewState\"[^>]*value=\"([^\"]*)\"");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

1) This will not work, if the ordering of the `name` and `value` changes.
2) This will not work if the double quotes are replaced with single quote in html source.