# Regex Show Multiple Results

Tags: c#, regex

i want to get the value between **UCase("PCE")** i use this patern - **UCase(.+)** - but it shows me the whole string

```
Strings.UCase("PCE") == Strings.UCase(_with7.Columns(eventArgs.ColIndex).Name)) || 
Strings.UCase("TVA") == Strings.UCase(_with7.Columns(eventArgs.ColIndex).Name))
```

Thanks

Comment: You have to backslash the parenthesis since a parenthesis is part of the regex language.

Answer (score 0):

> i use this patern - UCase(.+) - but it shows me the whole string

My guess is that you're doing something like this:

```
var InputString = "UCase(\"PCE\")";
var Result = Regex.Match(InputString, "UCase\\(\"(.+)\"\\)");
```

That will match your full string, yes.
But if you add one more line of code, looking for captured **groups**, you'll get:

```
var GroupResult = Result.Groups[1].Value; // "PCE"; Groups[0] is again the full string
```

You can see (and test) an example [here](https://regex101.com/r/k726to/1).
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650909/regex-help-with-extracting-certain-part-of-a-string/5651002#5651002) for comparison.

You can find more details about groups (i.e. subset of expressions you extract using brackets) [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).