# Insert space before and after specific keywords if they are found in string using C#

Tags: c#, split

I have a dumb string

> `Today the auto industry is booming. Automated machines are big part of it and it's working great. They are doing very big autonomous work.`

I want to be able to give a dictionary of keywords as a `List<string>`.

Then I want to search these keywords in my text. If the keyword is found check if contains space before and after. If yes do nothing. If doesn't contain then add space before of after. So the keyword can be part of a word at the beginning middle or end. So basically make the keywords individual words within the text.

Example keywords: `auto, work, the`

For my text

> `Today the auto industry is booming. Automated machines are big part of it and it's working great. They are doing very big autonomous work.`

the result should be:

> `Today the auto industry is booming. Auto mated machines are big part of it and it's work ing great. The y are doing very big auto nomous work .`

Comment: Why without regex? This feels like a perfect time for regex...

Comment: I don't understand regex so well ... but of course it's fine.

Comment: You can search for, it's a classical regex I think. See :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650909/regex-for-extracting-certain-part-of-a-string

Comment: because it should be as a single word

Comment: For each word, replace the word with `" word "`. Then replace `"  word"` (two spaces at front) with `" word"` and `"word  "` (two spaces at end) with `"word "` to deal with double space issues (i.e. there was already a space there).

Comment: What is the expected output if the input was `Hello theautowork the autoworker whatever`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that does that. It goes keyword by keyword, comparing by ignoring case. If the keyword is found, checks whether there is a space before and/or after and adds it.

```
public static string AddSpacesAroundWords(string text, List<string> words)
{
    foreach(string word in words) {
        int index = 0;
        while(index < text.Length) {
            index = text.IndexOf(word, index, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            if(index == -1) {
                // no occurrence of this word anymore
                break;
            }
            // check if there is a space at the beginning of the word
            if(index > 0 && text[index - 1] != ' ') {
                text = text.Insert(index++ - 1, " ");
            }
            // check if there is a space at the end of the word
            if(index + word.Length < text.Length && text[index + word.Length] != ' ') {
                text = text.Insert(index++ + word.Length, " ");
            }
            index += word.Length;
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Usage:

```
string original = "Today the auto industry is booming. Automated machines are big part of it and it's working great. They are doing very big autonomous work.";
var words = new List<string> { "auto", "work", "the" };
string result = AddSpacesAroundWords(original, words);
// result is now "Today the auto industry is booming. Auto mated machines are big part of it and it's work ing great. The y are doing very big auto nomous work ."
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a rework/variation of GregaMohorko's answer, which I upvoted:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbKeywords.Text = "auto, work, the";
    textBox1.Text = "Today the auto industry is booming. Automated machines are big part of it and it's working great. They are doing very big autonomous work.";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = AddSpaceAroundWords(textBox1.Text, tbKeywords.Text);        
}

private string AddSpaceAroundWords(string sentence, string CommaSeparatedKeyWords)
{
    int index;
    string keyword;
    foreach (string key in CommaSeparatedKeyWords.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        index = 0;
        keyword = key.Trim();       
        while ((index = sentence.IndexOf(keyword, index, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) != -1)
        {
            if ((index > 0) && (sentence[index - 1] != ' '))
            {
                sentence = sentence.Insert(index++, " ");
            }
            if (((index + keyword.Length) < sentence.Length) && (sentence[index + keyword.Length] != ' ')) {
                sentence = sentence.Insert(index++ + keyword.Length, " ");
            }
            index += keyword.Length;
        }
    }
    return sentence;
}
```