# C# Table Raw filter

Tags: c#, api

Need bit of help, the below coding write all the errors to an html file for emailing. I only want it to write the first Row_Number, for each customer erroring product.
i.e
Customer No   Customer Name    Erro Date               Message
Joh            ddd company    14/10/2022 08:55:49     Property values were not valid: [{"isValid":false,"message":"TTTT01 LA Diner Battered Chicken Bites  was not one of the allowed options: [label
Mike           eee Company    14/10/2022 08:55:49     Property values were not valid: [{"isValid":false,"message":"XXXX02 LA Diner Breaded Chicken Bites  was not one of the allowed options: [label:

At the moment in my current coding It rights multiple products that's erroring for each customer so the file becomes really big. Please see the attached image of the error example I am generating at the moment. Thanks in advance.[image]
My coding

```
 public static void UpdateCompanies(List<Company> companies)
    {
        if (companies.Count == 0)
            return;

        // Update error email.
        var tableRows = new StringBuilder();

        //var companiesNotUpdated = new List<Company>();
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (Company company in companies)
        {
            ActionResponse actionResponse = UpdateCompany(company);

            if (!actionResponse.WasSuccessful)
            {
                //companiesNotUpdated.Add(company);

                // This is at the start so we can check if there were any errors.
                counter++;
                 
                string tableRow = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(_baseFilePath, "UpdateErrorsTableRow.html"));
               
                    {
                tableRow = tableRow.Replace("{{ ROW_NUMBER }}", counter.ToString());
                tableRow = tableRow.Replace("{{ CUSTOMER_NO }}", company.CustomerNo);
                tableRow = tableRow.Replace("{{ CUSTOMER_NAME }}", company.CustomerName);
                tableRow = tableRow.Replace("{{ ERROR_DATE }}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                tableRow = tableRow.Replace("{{ ERROR_MESSAGE }}", actionResponse.ErrorMessage);

                tableRows.Append(tableRow);
                 }

            }
        }

        string updateErrorsEmail = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(_baseFilePath, "UpdateErrors.html"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `actionResponse.ErrorMessage` is just a string. You could write a regex expression to extract only the part of the message you want. Here's a separate example: [Regex for extracting certain part of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650909/regex-for-extracting-certain-part-of-a-string)

For your case a regex like this might do the trick:

```
var match = Regex.Match(applicationResponse.ErrorMessage, "\"message\":\"(.*):");
//... removed excess code for brevity
tableRow = tableRow.Replace("{{ ERROR_MESSAGE }}", match[0].Groups[1].Value);
```